# How to filter and show a nested array using underscore, jquery and handlebars

Tags: jquery, filter, underscore.js, where-clause, handlebars.js

I have this data:

```
data = { grouplist: [
                {name: "one", optionlist: [{optionitem:"green"},{optionitem:"red"}]},
                {name: "two", optionlist: [{optionitem:"yellow"},{optionitem:"red"},{optionitem:"blue"}]},
                {name: "three", optionlist: [{optionitem:"green"}]},
                {name: "four", optionlist: [{optionitem:"blue"},{optionitem:"red"}]}
            ]};
```

And I would like to filter the data to just show items with the "optionitem:"red"" assigned.

I.e only items from grouplist should show:

```
{name: "one", optionlist: [{optionitem:"green"},{optionitem:"red"}]},
{name: "two", optionlist: [{optionitem:"yellow"},{optionitem:"red"},{optionitem:"blue"}]},
{name: "four", optionlist: [{optionitem:"blue"},{optionitem:"red"}]}
```

I've tried using _.filter and also _.where but I can't get it to filter on a nested level of data whilst still returning the parent level of data also.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: `_.filter(data.grouplist, function(n){
return ~n.name.toLowerCase().indexOf("one");

  }
);`

This will return me the item named 'one', but I'd like to return me items with red.

Any help would be great

Answer (score 1):

You have the filter part right, but your predicate function must be adapted. To do so, you can use [some](http://underscorejs.org/#some).

> Returns true if any of the values in the list pass the predicate truth test. Short-circuits and stops traversing the list if a true element is found.

```
_.filter(data.grouplist, function(n){ 
    return _.some(n.optionlist, function(option){ 
        return option.optionitem == "red";
    });
 });
```